# regular expression in javascript escaping backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a portion of a url to include in a script using regex and the results are null. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried using regexr.com and it works fine there but doesn't seem to work in my code.

```
var url = window.location.href //this would return ..//path/##-###/something.aspx
var regex = /\d{2}-\d{3}/g
var projNumb = url.match(regex);
document.write(projNumb);
```

If I substitute a string with 12-234-567 in for the window.location.href it would return 34-567. Seems to have something to do with the "/" before the ## but if I escape the / like // javascript sees it as a comment.

End result, I'm trying to get 17-123 out of http://www.example.com/path1/path2/17-123/home.aspx and assign it to a variable for a query.

Comment: `var regex = /\d{2}-\d{3}` is not valid... typo writing the question?

Comment: Yeah, left out the /g will edit to fix. With the /g it works fine in regexr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression should start and end with the `/` and if you want to match a `/` than you need to escape it.

```
window.location.pathname.match(/\/(\d{2}-\d{3})\//)
```

Comment: The example URL you gave, this code works. What is the problem? `var match = url.match(/\/(\d{2}-\d{3})\//); if(match) { console.log(match[1]); }`

Comment: What is the path that is failing? `console.log(window.location.pathname)` And so you realize it returns an array?

Comment: Sorry having issues getting code to format in comments. Feel like an idiot. I'm indenting 4 spaces but doing nothing. Still returning null. If I assign window.location.pathname to a variable and use document write it writes out as expected. As soon as I attach the `.match(/\/(\d{2}-\d{3})\//)` it returns null. 
I tried this also in codepen just using a variable with a string like the example url and it returns 2 values "/17-123/,17-123"

Comment: So what is the pathname? Formatting surround code with ` on each side, there is no code blocks in comments

Comment: I put in:
`var projnumb = window.location.pathname.match(/\/(d{2}-\d{3})\//);`
`document.write(projnumb);` I get null as a return value.
If I put in the following:
`var projnumb = window.location.pathname;`
`document.write(projnumb);`
**I get a pathname:** /air/52/AVMI/529/projects/Proj-Office/site-templates/01-001/default.aspx

Comment: `"/air/52/AVMI/529/projects/Proj-Office/site-templates/01-001/‌​default.aspx".match(/\/(\d{2}-\d{3})\//)[0]` is working for me. You really should use `console.log()` to debug and not document.write.  There also appears to be some strange characters between the `/` and `d`

Comment: Also, I tried this using codepen and it worked if I just made the variable a static string with  the original example url but I get two results. I get " /17-123/,17-123" but I at least get a result. The prod site is an Internal SharePoint site.

Comment: I logged to console and got an error "Invalid Character" at line 1728 which is this line: `var projnumb = window.location.pathname.mat‌​ch(/\/(\d{2}-\d{3})\‌​//)[0];`

Comment: I got home and tried in my office365 sharepoint site with a url that matches the pattern and it works fine. I'll look and see what the deal is with what I have at work.
Thanks for your time epascarello !